# Is it possible to define a shell script using the c# lang (dotnet core runtime)?

Tags: c#, linux, bash, shell

for example to define a script that print "hello".

I can do the following with nodejs (hello_node)

```
#!/bin/node
console.log(`hello ${process.argv[2]}`)
```

Then I will call it

```
./hello_node "world"
```

Also in Python

```
#!/bin/python3.7
print("hello world")
```

The same works in PHP and ruby, is there a way to do this in C# ?

I've tried the below, but it didn't work

```
#!/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet run
using System;

public static class Program {

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + args[1]);
  }

}
```

Comment: What "didn't work"? Assuming the code is correctly embedded in a project, this *should* work. Just keep in mind that [arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) start at zero, so if you do `dotnet run World`, you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` and if you do `dotnet run World Something`, you should get `Hello Something` (ignoring the zeroth parameter `World`). -- and a project is easily created as described here: [.NET Tutorial - Hello World in 10 minutes](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started-with-dotnet-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

A shebang (`#!`) tells the it to open the file with a specific command.

The `dotnet run` command can only be used to run projects, not single files.

You could try using the dotnet-script tool, but you'd need to setup the directory which might be a big downside based on what you're trying to achieve

https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script